# Calculation groups with specific columns in r

Tags: r, tidyverse

The pattern my data is like this

```html
df1<-read.table(text="Car1 Car2 Car3 Time1 Time2 Time3
22 33 90 20 90 20
11 45 88 10 80 30
22 33 40 40 10 10
11 45 40 10 10 40
11 45 88 10 12 60
22 45 90 60 20 100",header=TRUE)
```

I want to calculate mean and SD based on Car and time. The point is Car 1 corresponds to Time1, Car2 corresponds to  Time 2 and Car3 Corresponds to Time3 and so on.

I want to get the following table :

```html
Car1 Mean SD
11 10 0
22 40 20
Car2  
33 xx xx
45 xx xx
Car3  
40 xx xx
88 xx xx
90 xx xx
```

I have tried:

```html
df1 %>% group_by(Car1,Car2,Car3) %>% 
summarise(mean=mean(Time,SD=sd(Time))
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), 
     measure = patterns("Car", "Time"), 
     value.name = c("Car", "Time"), 
     variable.name = "group"
     )[, .(Mean = mean(Time), Sd = sd(Time)), .(group, Car)]

#     group   Car  Mean       Sd
# 1:      1    22  40.0 20.00000
# 2:      1    11  10.0  0.00000
# 3:      2    33  50.0 56.56854
# 4:      2    45  30.5 33.28163
# 5:      3    90  60.0 56.56854
# 6:      3    88  45.0 21.21320
# 7:      3    40  25.0 21.21320
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `pivot_longer` where we reshape from 'wide' to 'long' format and group by the 'group1' index and 'Car', get the `mean` and `sd` of 'Time' by `summarise`ing the 'Time'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "group"),
        names_sep="(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d+)") %>%
  group_by(group, Car) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(Time), SD = sd(Time))
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   group [3]
#  group   Car  Mean    SD
#  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1        11  10     0  
#2 1        22  40    20  
#3 2        33  50    56.6
#4 2        45  30.5  33.3
#5 3        40  25    21.2
#6 3        88  45    21.2
#7 3        90  60    56.6
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(split.default(df1, gsub("\\D+", "", names(df1))), function(x){
    d = gsub("\\D+", "", names(x)[1])
    x %>%
        group_by(!!sym(paste0("Car", d))) %>%
        summarise(mean = mean(!!sym(paste0("Time", d))),
                  sd = sd(!!sym(paste0("Time", d)))) %>%
        ungroup()
})
```

Comment: @user202, check now

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can easily segregate your data into Time and Cars, then you can do this using `loop`, assuming you have data into structure as provided by you.

```
cars <- df1[1:3]
Time <- df1[4:6]

ls <- list()
for(i in 1:ncol(cars)) {
  ls[[i]] <- aggregate(Time[i], by = cars[i], FUN = function(x) c(mean(x), sd(x)))
}
```

### ls

Data  for the results is:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Car1 = c(22L, 11L, 22L, 11L, 11L, 22L), Car2 = c(33L, 
45L, 33L, 45L, 45L, 45L), Car3 = c(90L, 88L, 40L, 40L, 88L, 90L
), Time1 = c(20L, 10L, 40L, 10L, 10L, 60L), Time2 = c(90L, 80L, 
10L, 10L, 12L, 20L), Time3 = c(20L, 30L, 10L, 40L, 60L, 100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```